# Insert value into JSON array if it is not already present

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm building a bash script that will read the response from an API and insert a value within a [] list (not {} array) if the value isn't present.  Fake example response from API:

```
#response.json contains:

{
    "foods": {
        "menu": [
            "tacos",
            "spaghetti",
            "pizza",
            "chicken_florentine",
            "bacon_cheeseburge",
            "chow_mein",
            "sushi",
            "chocolate",
            "whiskey"
        ]
    }
}
```

The variable from my bash script is `order="lasagna"`.  If `'foods.menu[]'` contains `$order` then do nothing, else insert `$order` value into `'foods.menu[]'`.

Using bash variable `order="lasagna"` which currently doesn't exist in `'foods.menu[]'`, the resulting json should be:

```
{
    "foods": {
        "menu": [
            "tacos",
            "spaghetti",
            "pizza",
            "chicken_florentine",
            "bacon_cheeseburge",
            "chow_mein",
            "sushi",
            "chocolate",
            "whiskey",
            "lasagna" <----
        ]
    }
}
```

I started with trying a bash `for` loop and variations of jq's `if-then-else`, `select`, and `contains` but went down a rabbit hole.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a loop for that

```
jq --arg order lasagna '.foods.menu |= if index($order) then . else . + [$order] end' response.json
```

But you may need one for inserting multiple orders

```
jq 'reduce $ARGS.positional[] as $order (.;
  .foods.menu |= if index($order) then . else . + [$order] end
)' response.json --args apple banana sushi
```

Comment: Thank you @oguz-ismail.  How should I handle a list like `orders=("apple" "banana" "sushi")`?

I tried:
`jq --argjson orders "$(jq -n --args '$ARGS.positional' "${orders[@]}")" \
    '.foods.menu |= if index($orders) then . else . + $orders end' response.json`

But each item in `$orders` isn't accurately checked against the existing list and duplicates show up.

Comment: @phoeneous Welcome. The answer to that depends on whether you want items initially resided in `.foods.menu` to be retained or not. If not, glenn's answer is on the right track and this is not.

Comment: Thanks @oguz-ismail, the items initially residing in `.foods.menu` should be retained but unique.

Comment: @phoeneous It's easier then `jq '.foods.menu |= (. + $ARGS.positional | unique)' response.json --args apple banana sushi`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this fits with any unspoken requirements.

Add the item regardless, and then `unique` the results:

```bash
echo "$result" | jq --arg order pizza '.foods.menu |= (. + [$order] | unique)'
```

```json
{
  "foods": {
    "menu": [
      "bacon_cheeseburge",
      "chicken_florentine",
      "chocolate",
      "chow_mein",
      "pizza",
      "spaghetti",
      "sushi",
      "tacos",
      "whiskey"
    ]
  }
}
```

The resulting array is sorted. If there were any duplicates in the input, those are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using the [alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F) `//` to default to the array's `length` for the item's index:

```bash
jq --arg order 'lasagna' '
  (.foods.menu | .[index($order) // length]) = $order
' response.json
```

Adding a list of items in the same manner:

```bash
jq '.foods.menu |= reduce $ARGS.positional[] as $order (.;
  .[index($order) // length] = $order
)' response.json --args 'lasagna' 'sushi' 'milk'
```